# how to intercept processing when Session.IsNewSession is true

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a small 4-page application for my customers to work through.  They fill out information.  If they let it sit too long, and the Session timeout out, I want to pop up a javascript alert that their session has expired, and that they need to start over.  At that point, then redirected to the beginning page of the application.

I'm getting some strange behavior.  I'm stepping through code, forcing my Sessioni.IsNewSession to be true.  At this point, I write out a call to Javascript to a Literal Control placed at the bottom of the .  The javascript is called, and the redirection occurs.

However, what is happening is.. I am pressing a button which is more or less a "Next Page" button and triggering this code.  The next page is being displayed, and then the Alert  and redirection occurs.  The result I was expecting was to stay on the same page I received the "Timeout", with the alert to pop-up over it, then redirection.

I'm checking for Session.IsNewSession in a BaseClass for these pages, overriding the OnInit event.

Any ideas why I am getting this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There multiple ways u can do this. Have hava Script timer as per u session timeout (Default is 20 min). After 19 min just rasise a alert on client and submit the page to the same page to refresh. This may not good option given user would have entered lot of stuff already

Or other way is don't session time out this page. U can do this on back ground just refresh the page after 19 min (U can do this by placing one div and iframe or image request on the server.). This might be good experiance for the user the reason is he don't have to enter the content again. Talking to u client giving this kind of option is worth sometimes.

Comment: Those two scenarios aren't an option at this point.  

Why is the code not performing what I am expecting?